# adjust margin in just 1 div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Well, now I've this problem, I want to adjust just the margin on the "c2" but when I set it to X, it changes the "c1" div margin :S

Here's the code I'm using:

```
<header>
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <center><h1>Bienvenidos a JVasconcelos.me</h1></center>
    </div>
</header>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 col-centered">
            <div class="c1">
                <div class="c2">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quis inventore illum quaerat laboriosam eos, vel sed suscipit cumque laborum est animi aliquid tempora iusto beatae quam quisquam porro dolore! Ullam tenetur doloribus ducimus, totam voluptatum, deleniti vero voluptatem eius architecto velit neque voluptas aliquam quidem sed eveniet! Nobis ex eos iste dolorum tempora doloremque non deleniti, aperiam quibusdam corrupti officia consequatur, impedit. Exercitationem debitis iste voluptatum, illo nulla iure culpa ex fugit, aliquid dolorem excepturi, impedit voluptates quae quidem error earum natus, provident eum vitae. Tempore ducimus laborum voluptates, qui aspernatur odit dolorum modi quas cupiditate unde quam earum amet!
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

## CSS

```
div.c1 { height: 100vh; background: #417ba1; margin-top: -30px; padding: 0px 30px; }
div.c2 { height: 90%; background: #fff; margin-top: 0px; padding: 60px 30px; }
.jumbotron { background: url("../img/header_bg.png") no-repeat; height: 100%; }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the border of the `c1` and `c2` are [collapsing](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#collapsing-margins). You have to hide the `overflow` (with `overflow: hidden` or any overflow different that default, which is visible) of the container to avoid that the `c1` also get the `margin` of `c2`.

```css
div.c1 { height: 100vh; background: #417ba1; overflow: hidden; margin-top: -30px; padding: 0px 30px; }
div.c2 { height: 90%; background: #fff; margin-top: 20px; padding: 60px 30px; }
.jumbotron { background: url("../img/header_bg.png") no-repeat; height: 100%; }
```

```html
<header>
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <center><h1>Bienvenidos a JVasconcelos.me</h1></center>
    </div>
</header>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 col-centered">
            <div class="c1">
                <div class="c2">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quis inventore illum quaerat laboriosam eos, vel sed suscipit cumque laborum est animi aliquid tempora iusto beatae quam quisquam porro dolore! Ullam tenetur doloribus ducimus, totam voluptatum, deleniti vero voluptatem eius architecto velit neque voluptas aliquam quidem sed eveniet! Nobis ex eos iste dolorum tempora doloremque non deleniti, aperiam quibusdam corrupti officia consequatur, impedit. Exercitationem debitis iste voluptatum, illo nulla iure culpa ex fugit, aliquid dolorem excepturi, impedit voluptates quae quidem error earum natus, provident eum vitae. Tempore ducimus laborum voluptates, qui aspernatur odit dolorum modi quas cupiditate unde quam earum amet!
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked fine :) Thanks a lot :P

Comment: @JoseAntonio You are welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

Ah.  You're looking for

```
.c1 {
    overflow: auto; // or hidden or overlay
}
```

This behavior is due to the [collapsing margins](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#collapsing-margins) part of the box model spec.  Putting `overflow: auto|hidden|overlay` on the parent will establish a new block formatting context and stop the margins from collapsing.

Comment: Thanks, it helped me a lot :P

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean when you change the margin-top on the div.c2 your div.c1 also shifts down. This is due to the default definition of a div+div construct.

To achieve what you want you will need to create the following extra css definition on your div.c1:

```
display: inline-block;
```

Have a look at this codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/beNjbW

Answer (score 0):

Difference of or greater margin of c1 or c2 will be rendered due to collapsible margins.

In this case your total distance will be 0 (they cancel each other):

```
div.c1 {
  margin-top: -30px;
}

div.c2 {
  margin-top: 30px;
}
```

In this case your distance will be 10px from the top:

```
div.c1 {
  margin-top: -30px;
}

div.c2 {
  margin-top: 40px;
}
```

One of top margins can be omitted in this case. You can control the distance to header by adjusting margin-top of either one

[codePen example](http://codepen.io/Legited/pen/mEyjVE)